# What goes inside the block?

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

After going through lecture 1, where can I find out more information about what is stored in each block in blockchain ?

I am guessing that all the UTxOs and the script addresses will be there, as well as the (on-chain) plutus scripts themselves.

If the UTxOs are all in the blockchain, is it the user/wallet responsibility to safely maintain all the UTxOs that he owns ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The UTxO set is **not** on the blockchain. Blocks contain transactions (including input UTxO references, output addresses, scripts, certificates (eg for delegation and other purposes) etc.

The UTxO set is an ephemeral data structure than can be built from the original genesis state and then apply blocks to it.

Comment: When, say, Alice sends money to Bob, how does Bob know which UTxO output belongs to him (so that he can consume that money) ? Is it the job of the wallet to scan through all new UTxOs that are generated in the blockchain, then compare this new UTxO with Bob's wallet -  and if it matches, add the new UTxO to Bob's wallet ? Is this a correct assumption ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.